# How to make objects come up one after another?

Tags: particles

I want to make an animation with spikes shooting up from the ground. While I've tried the hair particle systems, it's too uniformed for me. I'm looking for the spikes to shoot up individually without me going through it one by one. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can control rate of particles by changing Emission number, if you decrease it enough then spikes will shoot less frequently

[image]

you can also animate just one, and then duplicate it and simply offset animation, in case you want exact manual control